# Get value in some column into one column using query in spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I expect to spit number and dot based on some columns into one column as shown in picture.
I want to use query but I am difficult to find best formula.
The picture with green color below is what I expected to.

[image]

Thank for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only going to have one name per timestamp row, a simple approach would be:

```
=arrayformula({"Name";if(A2:A<>"",regexextract({D2:D&E2:E&F2:F},"\d\.\ (.*)"),)})
```

[image]